# Issue with parsing the data into an integer JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file

```
{
    "Val1":120,
    "Val2":60,
    "Val3":50
}
```

I need to pass those into two Global Arrays.

```
1st Array = ["Val1","Val2","Val3"]
2nd Array = [120,60,50]
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far? It sounds like a simple problem: Array1 is `Object.keys(o)` and Array2 is `Object.values(o)`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.keys` & `Object.values`. Both of them will return array. `Object.keys` return array of keys and `Object.values` creates an array of values

```js
let obj = {
  "Val1": 120,
  "Val2": 60,
  "Val3": 50
}

let array1 = Object.keys(obj);
let array2 = Object.values(obj);

console.log(array1, array2)
```

Comment: Nice solution ! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop like the one here:

```
var jsonObject = {
    "Val1":120,
    "Val2":60,
    "Val3":50
};

var arr1 = [];
var arr2 = [];

for(key in jsonObject) {
    arr1.push(key);
    arr2.push(jsonObject[key]);
}

console.log('Keys: ', arr1);
console.log('Values: ', arr2);
```